# there is almost nothing / there isn't much left / there aren't many left

Tags: dummy-pronouns

Are all answers on the question idiomatic?

I saw the second answer in my English training course, but my version was the first answer. I don't understand why "there isn't much left" is used with countable noun. Is it possible?

***Are there many sweets on the table?***

> No, **there is almost nothing.**

> No, **there isn't much left.**

> No, **there aren't many left.**

Comment: If your course book suggests that 'There isn't much left' is a possible answer, it is wrong. "Are there many sweets left?" "No, there aren't many." "Is there much snow left in the garden?" "No, there isn't much."

Comment: Kate, is the first answer correct?

Comment: @Sergey - there is only one correct answer.

Comment: Informally, you will hear many people answer with "much", though.  People are not always 100% precise in how they speak.

Comment: Obviously if there is almost nothing on the table, there aren't many sweets - but it isn't a _direct_ answer to the question.

Comment: Is it not an idiomatic answer in that context? It sounds good in my native language.

Comment: In real life, someone might answer "No - in fact, there's almost nothing/hardly anything left" if the table had been full of sweets and other things. But from a grammatical point of view, the answer they are looking for would be "No, there aren't many [sweets] left."